# Wrapping my own class data with private properties

Tags: c#, list

I make a wrapper for my application data. But first, my code:

```
public class FakeData
{
    private List<User> users { get; set; }
    private List<Project> projects { get; set; }

    public FakeData()
    {
        users = new List<User>
        {
            //Some Data here
        };

        projects = new List<Project>
        {
            //Some data here
        };

    }

    public void Initialize() => context = new FakeData();
    public List<User> GetUsers() => context.users; //i get an error here

    private FakeData context { get; set; }

}
```

What i want to do, is wrapped `FakeData()` class. I want to have private lists and object state in this class. Why VS telling me, that type `List<User>` is less available than method `GetUsers()`? How to make it properly when i want to have acces to object and lists only by accces public methods?

Thanks for any advices

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers, it was really helpful!

What i want to get by wrapping my `FakeData()` class is to not make public propertys from `Users` and `Projects`. I want to have acces to it only by public methods that i will write in `FakeData` class

Comment: Is the class User public?

Comment: Yes, it was private. If i change `User` class to `public` i lost everything that i keep in mind. I want to have acces to data only by wrapped `FakeData()` class. I dont want to make an instance of `User()` in my app everything :D

Comment: If you want to prevent creation of user objects, make the constructor private or internal.

Comment: If i make an internal constructor i will have acces to it only in constructor's namespace? 

For example, i can use internal constructor that is in namspace `Project.Models` only in classes that is in same namespace?

Comment: @michasaucer instead of asking, you can just try with internal and see the behavior and then try with private contructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `context`'s current instance `users` property outside that even in the other instance of same type.

As you have defined `users` private it can only be accessed from within the `context` and you cannot access it outside that.

While you are trying to access the `users` property.

[FROM MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private):

> Private access is the least permissive access level. Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared

See more examples of these [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private)

You can change the `set` to private if you don't want it to be modified outside the class :

```
public List<User> users { get; private set; }
```

Now your code would work fine and you can read the `users` property.

Comment: I forget about private set, thanks! WIth `private set` i will have acces to edit data only from public accesing methods in class?

Comment: you can set it within the body of the class

Comment: Look into my edit please. I dont want to make instance of `User()` or `Project()` anywhere in my project. How to make `constuctor` of this classes visible only in classes with the same namespace like `FakeData()` (FakeData, Users and Projects are in the same namespace). For example, for `internal User()` constructor i still can make object of User in another class in diffrent namespace

Comment: Internal will make it only visible in that particular namespace only. read about access modifiers in the msdn link posted above

Answer (score 1):

Looks like class `User` is not public, you need to change that. Reason: a method that is `public` can only return things that are also `public`.

Answer (score 1):

*Why VS telling me, that type List is less available than method GetUsers()?*

You need to modify your `User` class to ensure it is public, so it is at least as available as your `FakeData` class which is referencing it.

```
public class User
{
}
```

*How to make it properly when i want to have access to object and lists only by access public methods?*

Expose your properties as public.

```
public class FakeData
{
    public List<User> Users { get; private set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; private set; }

    public FakeData()
    {
        Users = new List<User>
        {
            //Some Data here
        };

        Projects = new List<Project>
        {
            //Some data here
        };
    }
}
```